# What is #define NAME ((LPCSTR) 5) ?

Tags: c, windows

What does this line of code mean?

```
#define NAME ((LPCSTR) 5)
```

If I define a variable, `NAME *tmp`, then use it like this:

```
((LPCSTR) 5) *tmp;
```

What does that code do?

Note: `LPCSTR` is `typedef __nullterminated CONST CHAR *LPCSTR`

Comment: Why are you trying to use NAME as a type? It clearly isn't. It would help if you would say where you found that definition of NAME and what the context is.

Comment: No its not compiling.. I am trying to build application where structure is defined like that with variable. You can verify the Wincrypt.h file in windows hwere #define X509_NAME ((LPCSTR) 7). in structure they have used that define to declare a variable. may be i am wrong in declaring variable i will check that. mean while can you explain the #define

Comment: yes exactly its wincrypt

Comment: Thank you one and all, In my source code I kept #undef for X509_NAME. It has been define already. wincrypt #define has been clash.

Comment: if it's already defined, why are you redefining it?

Comment: I am trying to build wpa_supplicant code which compatibile with all OS. In which same name they have used for openssl implementation. when i am trying to build in windows OS. its conflicting with wincrypt.h.

Comment: Please update the question title so it will be useful to future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a simple cast, it converts 5 to a character pointer (`__nullterminated CONST CHAR *`)

That's probably undefined behaviour by the standard, but sometimes used in real life.

- To address specific physical addresses on your machine - for example the kernel has to do this to configure cards, onbard chips, etc...
- To send special values in arguments or return values.. for example the call normally expects a pointer in the second argument, but if you pass "5" it meants something else.

As you can see, it's really a pointer, so what you've tried, `NAME *tmp;`, won't compile.

Comment: Nice explanation and usage of that particular cast

Answer (score 0):

Given the `LPCSTR` type, I'm guessing this is being used to load a resource in an EXE file:

```
#define MAKEINTRESOURCE(x) ((LPCTSTR)(x)) // in windows.h
#define IDR_FOO 1 // usually in IDE-generated resources.h

HRSRC res = FindResource(NULL,
                         MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_FOO),
                         MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_FOO));
```

This is commonplace in WinAPI apps, but I've never seen someone perform the cast themselves rather than use the standard `MAKEINTRESOURCE` macro.